# CSS Animated type blocked/blocking Hero Image with JS effect attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey UX Designer learning code here, please forgive my ignorance and crappy code.

I have a CSS animated type overlayed a Hero Image which also has a JS effect applied to it.

Originally I couldn't get both images to render. The type would render but you couldn't see the hero image behind it, or the hero image would appear but you couldn't see the type.

At first I thought it was some class applied to the type that was creating an opaque background over the hero image but I eliminated that possibility by selectively commenting out stuff.

Then I realized that I needed to put the type div inside the Hero Image div. I had done this before but I tried again and it worked! But the reason it worked is because I had just selectively commented out the Javascript effect that was being applied to the Hero Image.

So the problem must be the tilt-effect (the javascript effect) class. I however have very little knowledge of Javascript so I am unsure of what is causing this problem.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the way javascript is manipulating stuff on the page? I've had a similar problem before when I had a page with a footer and a responsive image gallery driven by JS. The html footer would render and then the JS gallery would re-position all the objects on the page. So I'm thinking something similar is happening here, maybe?

Here's a JSFiddle for the code: http://jsfiddle.net/thedonquixotic/8vv7t1as/2/

The Tilt FX stuff is the second section of code in the JS part, I've labeled it for ease of finding.

Relevant part of the HTML is as follows:

```
<!--Hero image with tilt effect-->

<div class="hero">

        <div class="hero__imgwrap">
            <!--<div class="grid__item">
    <a class="link link--kumya" href="About.html"><span data-letters="David French">David French</span></a>
            </div>-->
            <img class="hero__img tilt-effect" data-tilt-options='{ "opacity" : 0.3, "extraImgs" : 3, "movement": { "perspective" : 1700, "translateX" : -7, "translateY" : -7, "rotateX" : -7, "rotateY" : -7 } }' src="https://cdn.tutsplus.com/craft/uploads/2013/11/14-snowflakes-lay-paper-copy.jpg" alt="Welcome!" />
        </div>
</div>
<!--Hero image with tilt effect-->
```

Also here is the Javascript:

```
/**
 * tiltfx.js
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * 
 * Copyright 2015, Codrops
 * http://www.codrops.com
 */
;(function(window) {

    'use strict';

    /**
     * **************************************************************************
     * utils
     * **************************************************************************
     */

    // from https://gist.github.com/desandro/1866474
    var lastTime = 0;
    var prefixes = 'webkit moz ms o'.split(' ');
    // get unprefixed rAF and cAF, if present
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame;
    var cancelAnimationFrame = window.cancelAnimationFrame;
    // loop through vendor prefixes and get prefixed rAF and cAF
    var prefix;
    for( var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++ ) {
        if ( requestAnimationFrame && cancelAnimationFrame ) {
            break;
        }
        prefix = prefixes[i];
        requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame || window[ prefix + 'RequestAnimationFrame' ];
        cancelAnimationFrame  = cancelAnimationFrame  || window[ prefix + 'CancelAnimationFrame' ] ||
        window[ prefix + 'CancelRequestAnimationFrame' ];
    }

    // fallback to setTimeout and clearTimeout if either request/cancel is not supported
    if ( !requestAnimationFrame || !cancelAnimationFrame ) {
        requestAnimationFrame = function( callback, element ) {
            var currTime = new Date().getTime();
            var timeToCall = Math.max( 0, 16 - ( currTime - lastTime ) );
            var id = window.setTimeout( function() {
                callback( currTime + timeToCall );
            }, timeToCall );
            lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
            return id;
        };

        cancelAnimationFrame = function( id ) {
            window.clearTimeout( id );
        };
    }

    function extend( a, b ) {
        for( var key in b ) { 
            if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                a[key] = b[key];
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    // from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#position
    function getMousePos(e) {
        var posx = 0;
        var posy = 0;
        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        if (e.pageX || e.pageY)     {
            posx = e.pageX;
            posy = e.pageY;
        }
        else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)    {
            posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
                + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
                + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        return {
            x : posx,
            y : posy
        }
    }

    // from http://www.sberry.me/articles/javascript-event-throttling-debouncing
    function throttle(fn, delay) {
        var allowSample = true;

        return function(e) {
            if (allowSample) {
                allowSample = false;
                setTimeout(function() { allowSample = true; }, delay);
                fn(e);
            }
        };
    }

    /***************************************************************************/

    /**
     * TiltFx fn
     */
    function TiltFx(el, options) {
        this.el = el;
        this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
        extend( this.options, options );
        this._init();
        this._initEvents();
    }

    /**
     * TiltFx options.
     */
    TiltFx.prototype.options = {
        // number of extra image elements (div with background-image) to add to the DOM - min:1, max:5 (for a higher number, it's recommended to remove the transitions of .tilt__front in the stylesheet.
        extraImgs : 2,
        // the opacity value for all the image elements.
        opacity : 0.7,
        // by default the first layer does not move.
        bgfixed : true,
        // image element's movement configuration
        movement : {
            perspective : 1000, // perspective value
            translateX : -10, // a relative movement of -10px to 10px on the x-axis (setting a negative value reverses the direction)
            translateY : -10, // a relative movement of -10px to 10px on the y-axis 
            translateZ : 20, // a relative movement of -20px to 20px on the z-axis (perspective value must be set). Also, this specific translation is done when the mouse moves vertically.
            rotateX : 2, // a relative rotation of -2deg to 2deg on the x-axis (perspective value must be set)
            rotateY : 2, // a relative rotation of -2deg to 2deg on the y-axis (perspective value must be set)
            rotateZ : 0 // z-axis rotation; by default there's no rotation on the z-axis (perspective value must be set)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize: build the necessary structure for the image elements and replace it with the HTML img element.
     */
    TiltFx.prototype._init = function() {
        this.tiltWrapper = document.createElement('div');
        this.tiltWrapper.className = 'tilt';

        // main image element.
        this.tiltImgBack = document.createElement('div');
        this.tiltImgBack.className = 'tilt__back';
        this.tiltImgBack.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.el.src + ')';
        this.tiltWrapper.appendChild(this.tiltImgBack);

        // image elements limit.
        if( this.options.extraImgs < 1 ) {
            this.options.extraImgs = 1;
        }
        else if( this.options.extraImgs > 5 ) {
            this.options.extraImgs = 5;
        }

        if( !this.options.movement.perspective ) {
            this.options.movement.perspective = 0;
        }

        // add the extra image elements.
        this.imgElems = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < this.options.extraImgs; ++i) {
            var el = document.createElement('div');
            el.className = 'tilt__front';
            el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.el.src + ')';
            el.style.opacity = this.options.opacity;
            this.tiltWrapper.appendChild(el);
            this.imgElems.push(el);
        }

        if( !this.options.bgfixed ) {
            this.imgElems.push(this.tiltImgBack);
            ++this.options.extraImgs;
        }

        // add it to the DOM and remove original img element.
        this.el.parentNode.insertBefore(this.tiltWrapper, this.el);
        this.el.parentNode.removeChild(this.el);

        // tiltWrapper properties: width/height/left/top
        this.view = { width : this.tiltWrapper.offsetWidth, height : this.tiltWrapper.offsetHeight };
    };

    /**
     * Initialize the events on the main wrapper.
     */
    TiltFx.prototype._initEvents = function() {
        var self = this,
            moveOpts = self.options.movement;

        // mousemove event..
        this.tiltWrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', function(ev) {
            requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                    // mouse position relative to the document.
                var mousepos = getMousePos(ev),
                    // document scrolls.
                    docScrolls = {left : document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft, top : document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop},
                    bounds = self.tiltWrapper.getBoundingClientRect(),
                    // mouse position relative to the main element (tiltWrapper).
                    relmousepos = {
                        x : mousepos.x - bounds.left - docScrolls.left,
                        y : mousepos.y - bounds.top - docScrolls.top
                    };

                // configure the movement for each image element.
                for(var i = 0, len = self.imgElems.length; i < len; ++i) {
                    var el = self.imgElems[i],
                        rotX = moveOpts.rotateX ? 2 * ((i+1)*moveOpts.rotateX/self.options.extraImgs) / self.view.height * relmousepos.y - ((i+1)*moveOpts.rotateX/self.options.extraImgs) : 0,
                        rotY = moveOpts.rotateY ? 2 * ((i+1)*moveOpts.rotateY/self.options.extraImgs) / self.view.width * relmousepos.x - ((i+1)*moveOpts.rotateY/self.options.extraImgs) : 0,
                        rotZ = moveOpts.rotateZ ? 2 * ((i+1)*moveOpts.rotateZ/self.options.extraImgs) / self.view.width * relmousepos.x - ((i+1)*moveOpts.rotateZ/self.options.extraImgs) : 0,
                        transX = moveOpts.translateX ? 2 * ((i+1)*moveOpts.translateX/self.options.extraImgs) / self.view.width * relmousepos.x - ((i+1)*moveOpts.translateX/self.options.extraImgs) : 0,
                        transY = moveOpts.translateY ? 2 * ((i+1)*moveOpts.translateY/self.options.extraImgs) / self.view.height * relmousepos.y - ((i+1)*moveOpts.translateY/self.options.extraImgs) : 0,
                        transZ = moveOpts.translateZ ? 2 * ((i+1)*moveOpts.translateZ/self.options.extraImgs) / self.view.height * relmousepos.y - ((i+1)*moveOpts.translateZ/self.options.extraImgs) : 0;

                    el.style.WebkitTransform = 'perspective(' + moveOpts.perspective + 'px) translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px,' + transZ + 'px) rotate3d(1,0,0,' + rotX + 'deg) rotate3d(0,1,0,' + rotY + 'deg) rotate3d(0,0,1,' + rotZ + 'deg)';
                    el.style.transform = 'perspective(' + moveOpts.perspective + 'px) translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px,' + transZ + 'px) rotate3d(1,0,0,' + rotX + 'deg) rotate3d(0,1,0,' + rotY + 'deg) rotate3d(0,0,1,' + rotZ + 'deg)';
                }
            });
        });

        // reset all when mouse leaves the main wrapper.
        /*this.tiltWrapper.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(ev) {
            setTimeout(function() {
            for(var i = 0, len = self.imgElems.length; i < len; ++i) {
                var el = self.imgElems[i];
                el.style.WebkitTransform = 'perspective(' + moveOpts.perspective + 'px) translate3d(0,0,0) rotate3d(1,1,1,0deg)';
                el.style.transform = 'perspective(' + moveOpts.perspective + 'px) translate3d(0,0,0) rotate3d(1,1,1,0deg)';
            }   
            }, 60);

        });*/

        // window resize
        window.addEventListener('resize', throttle(function(ev) {
            // recalculate tiltWrapper properties: width/height/left/top
            self.view = { width : self.tiltWrapper.offsetWidth, height : self.tiltWrapper.offsetHeight };
        }, 50));
    };

    function init() {
        // search for imgs with the class "tilt-effect"
        [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img.tilt-effect')).forEach(function(img) {
            new TiltFx(img, JSON.parse(img.getAttribute('data-tilt-options')));
        });
    }

    init();

    window.TiltFx = TiltFx;

})(window);
```

Comment: can you post ur javascript

Comment: It's on the JSFiddle. I cannot post it all to this comment. I'll see if I can edit it into my original post.

Comment: I saw your fiddle that is lot of JS

Comment: Yes sorry, I have quite a bit of stuff going on. I actually think I'm going to dial back how much js I'm using on the page, but this is a learning experience so I wanted to understand stuff before I nixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand it well so I created some modify
CSS:

```
    .grid__item {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        z-index: 1;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        top: 50%;
    }


    .link--kumya {
        font-family: "Syncopate",sans-serif;
        font-size: 6.5em;
        overflow: hidden;
        color: #242424;
        position: relative;
        left: -50%;
        top: -70px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

After you will change this part the type and animated background appear

Comment: Excellent, this works, thank you Michael. So I also want to make sure I understand why it works (i'm doing this project to learn after all). 

Basically the original grid_item was calculating the size of the object based on viewport right? And that was causing it problems, so you simplified it down to an absolute position and size?

Comment: your welcome :)
The calculated part was wrong because you defined "min-height: 460px;" it was cover the half site on viewport, so I removed it.
Unfortunately the animated string's second word is hide when the with is low maybe you can use a media query to prevent make a line break.
And finally the positions, please check it on the net because hard to explain for me :(
My first language is not English